# Steps to create a pocketsphinx wrapper in C#

Tags: c#, wrapper, pocketsphinx

pocketsphinx has a SWIG interface "pocketsphinx.i" to generate wrappers in multiple language and one of them is C#.

It is not clear how to run the swig command in Windows and how to use the resulting library in a NetCore C# project.

What are the steps required to generate the wrapper library and use it in a C# NetCore app?

Comment: https://github.com/garuma/PiHueSphinx
It isn't only about wrappers, but it should help you.

Answer (score 4):

There is an official swig-based wrapper in github, you can compile it for Linux with Make or for Microsoft with CMake:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/tree/master/swig/csharp

You can also check

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-unity-demo

Comment: Can you please articulate a bit more? Can you please provide an example of how to run the swig command and then use the resulting library in c#?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) to generate a C# wrapper for PocketSphinx lib, like it done here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-unity-demo/tree/master/Assets/Pocketsphinx